# Getting all the properties of a IDynamicMetaObjectProvider class when GetDynamicMemberNames isn't implemented

Tags: dynamic, .net-4.0

Is it possible to find all the available fields/properties that currently exist on dynamic object?

I want to do this for all objects that implement [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx). Using [GetDynamicMemberNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicmetaobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx) isn't suitable as it doesn't have to be fully implemented by custom dynamic classes, it can just return an empty enumeration.

I don't want to check for the presence of a named property i.e. "Name" or "Id", but I want to get a list of all the current properties, is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see how you could, no - a dynamic class can do what it likes when it comes to deeming a property to "exist" or not. You could write a dynamic class which allowed access to any property name so long as it's before midday, and nothing in the afternoon, for example.

`GetDynamicMemberNames()` is *the* way that a dynamic object is meant to advertise its members... if it doesn't do so, you'd basically be trying to solve the halting problem in order to find every "known" member.

Comment: Cheers, that's what I suspected, but I just wanted to check if I was missing something.

Comment: So basically Microsoft really dropped the ball with dynamics.

Comment: @Chris Marisic  Nope.  They did a decent job, you just can't expect them to handle every instance of "today you were that idiot programmer" that might exist. "You" being a self reference to who ever is trying to write the code.

Comment: @RogerWillcocks I don't make many positive statements about javascript often, but they seemed to have gotten it right that you can just foreach over an object's properties list.